# Android Genymotion Location (Google Services API) doesn't work

Tags: android, location, genymotion, genymotion-gps

I installed Google Services API in my Genymotion and after I downloaded the location example (https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/tree/master/BasicLocationSample) and it doesn't work, I set GPS and Data abled. I tested it on my real phone and it works! How to fix?

Google Maps find me on map.

Comment: I'm having the same issue on the android emulator

Comment: please be sure, you enabled maps api and if needed places api for android in android console developer (https://console.developers.google.com/home/dashboard). Also be sure you pasted correct key into your project. And what is more, be sure your genymotion has installed gapps and google services.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the emulator has Google Play Services installed, and that it's up to date.  You can update it to the latest version from the Play Store

Answer (score 1):

If Google Play Services on Android 6.0 crash everytime, you can try do  the same things in this sequence. Maybe it will work.

Here is what I did:

1. Install a latest Genymotion (version 2.6.0 in my case). Make sure
   the previous old (preview) Android 6.0 images are removed(Genymotion
   -> Settings -> Misc -> Clear cache).
2. Add a new virtualdevice, select Google Nexus 5X and Android 6.0
   image. It should download a new image from Genymotion website.Start
   created Google Nexus 5X - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 1080x1920 virtual device.
3. Flash Genymotion-ARM-Translation_v1.1.zip (drag&drop the zip file to
   virtual device window) and then restart the virtual device.
4. Flash gapps-L-4-21-15.zip and restart the virtual device again. Now
   add Google account in the virtual device via Settings -> Accounts ->
   Add account. Do not start Google Play! Ignore any crashes in sign in
   process.
5. Flash benzo-gapps-M-20151011-signed-chroma-r3.zip and restart the
   virtual device. Open Google Play in virtual device,update all
   installed applications.
6. Start Google Now with long touch on home button to force dialog with
   request to update Google Play Services. Update Google Play Services.
   Now the device is prepared with working Google Play and Google Play
   Services.

[Genymotion android 6.0 with Google play service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuaCg.png)

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your map is updated.
2. Check your PC location settings.

Answer (score -1):

To use Google Services Api in your genymotion you must follow this steps:

1) Download the [ARM Translation Installer v1.1(ARMTI)](http://filetrip.net/dl?4SUOrdcMRv)

2) Download the [Google Apps](http://www.android.gs/download-install-and-flash-google-apps-for-android/) for your specific Android version.

3) Drag and drop ARM Translation zip file to your emulator.

4) Reboot your emulator

5) Drag and  Drop the correct Google App version to your emulator

6) Reboot your emulator